# How inclusive should my CV's publications be?

Tags: publications, career-path, cv

I'm in the process of transitioning from industry to academia. Over the years I've been minor contributor to a number of publications and conference presentations and published once as an undergraduate in the school's peer-reviewed journal. This work was in a number of different fields that are different than the direction I'm going. Should all of this appear on my CV, or should I limit it to work done since going back to graduate school?

Comment: _I've been minor contributor to a number of publications_ — I don't understand what "minor contributor" means.  If you are an author, you must list them in your CV.  If you were not an author, you must _not_ list them in your CV.

Comment: @JeffE I mean that I've worked on some projects that had tens or hundreds of contributes so the citations are usually "et al." For example, something [like this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v486/n7403/full/nature11154.html) article.

Comment: Then yes, you're an author, and so yes, you should list them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically, your C.V. is expected to contain a fairly complete accounting of your life's scientific work (unless you are so advanced in your career that you can do a "selected publications" CV that just lists your greatest hits).

As such, it is generally best to list every publication on which you are listed as an author, no matter when it may have been published.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking the publications listed in a CV greatly evaluates your suitability for a particular scientific job. So it is always good to highlight the job related publications in the CV, no matter where and when it was published or who contributed less. Addition to this, list all other publications to increase the strength of your CV.